# Qt QML for a digital dashboard

Tags: qt, opengl, qml, dashboard

I am trying to develop in Qt QML a digital dashboard composed by a
speedometer and a tachometer with a needle each.
The problem of this design arises when i am involved in a rotation
of the needle: in this case, it has a jerky movement and it is not as
fluent as a real needle.
For instance, let us suppose to have 0 km/h i.e. the needle situated at
0 degrees and then I want to show 100 km/h situated at 90 degrees, the
needle reaches this angle with a sequence of fast jerks and not as a
unique fluent movement.
Does anyone have an idea to solve the inconvenient? Should I have to
use openGL?

I report the code below (I have used the QML Rotation function but it
is not enough)

```
Image {
    id: needle
    source: "../../images/needle.png"
    antialiasing: true
    transform: Rotation {
        id: needleRotation
        origin.x: 80;
        origin.y: 80;
        angle: 0
        Behavior on angle {
            RotationAnimation {
                id: needleRotationAnimation
                direction: RotationAnimation.Shortest;
                easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic;
                duration: 20;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 20ms seems really short for an animation, especially with a InOutCubic. For such fast transition, test with a Linear easing.

Answer (score 0):

I learn this today.

Try with the SmoothedAnimation instead, will achieve the objective you want, since SmoothedAnimation is calculating for the next paint() the current position, and not the initial position.

```
Image {
    id: needle
    source: "../../images/needle.png"
    antialiasing: true
    transform: Rotation {
    id: needleRotation
    origin.x: 80;
    origin.y: 80;
    angle: 0
    Behavior on angle {
        SmoothedAnimation {
            id: needleRotationAnimation
            easing.type: Easing.InOutCubic;
            duration: 20;
        }
    }
}
```

I will like to know a little bit more about your app since maybe its really necessary for you the

```
 direction: RotationAnimation.Shortest;
```

If its necessary just tell me and I'll try to have a further look!